# C++ regex::egrep not behaving like egrep

Tags: c++

Visual Studio 2019 (v142, /std:c++20) thinks this is false :

```
regex_match("99", regex("9",regex::egrep));
```

Not `grep -E` (alias `egrep`). It clearly wants a regex that spans the entire string (`^..$` or `.*9.*`). How to make it behave like `grep -E` ?

**Answer** (Yksisarvinen's comment) : Use `regex_search()` to check if it matches (don't ask why).

Comment: That's more about `std::regex_match`. `std::regex_match` must match whole string. `std::regex_search` can be satisfied with any substring.

Comment: You're right, regex_search works as expected. Silly me, I wanted to see if a string matches a regex, and went straight for `regex_match` without thinking :--] That's definitely a bug (in the specification maybe) : match as promised (`regex::egrep`), or don't accept two arguments (or return list of matches, not `bool`).